# How to use a calculated column in where condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, calculated-columns, oracle9i

How to use a calculated column in the  `where` condition in Oracle 9i?

I want to use something like

```
select decode (:pValue,1,
               select sysdate from dual,
               select activation_date from account where AcNo = 1234) as calDate
where caldate between startDate and endDate;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an in-line view:

```
select calcdate from
(
select startDate, endDate,
       decode (:pValue,1,
               select sysdate from dual,
               select activation_date from account where AcNo = 1234) as calcdate
)
where calcdate between startDate and endDate;
```

Comment: This will give ORA-00904: "caldate": invalid identifier

Comment: @SachinChorasiya - If you had *looked* at Tony's sample you would have noticed that it contained a typo (which I have now corrected).  It is a seriously bad idea to run code off the internet without properly reviewing first.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, Andrew.

Answer (score 3):

You could select your date from dual and join the results:

```
select * 
from   <<your table with startDate and endDate columns>> -- Since you ommited the main "from" clause from your statement
,      (
         select decode( :pValue
                      , 1, sysdate
                      , ( select activation_date from account where AcNo = 1234 )
                      ) as calDate
         from   dual
       ) c
where  c.calDate between startDate and endDate
... -- any other conditions you may need
```